# How to determine if a png picture has a transparency layer in Python

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I'm mostly using Pillow library but I can use something else.
I can extract the color layer including the alpha one.
I'm wondering if there is a way to quickly define if a picture **use** transparency or not.

```
pic = Image.open(path)
red, green, blue, alpha = pic.split()
```

Is there a way to see if the alpha is really used or only available because the format support it (e.g.: PNG)

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689512/determining-if-a-gif-is-transparent-in-python

Comment: Please clarify what use means, if an image has the format RGBA but every pixel has A=1, is that not using alpha?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about Pillow, but you can use `numpy` and `matplotlib.pyplot` to load and examine the image. These are very widespread python libraries.

You can load the image into an `numpy` array and check the length of the last axis. If it's  `3`, then there's no alpha channel. If it's `4`, there is an alpha channel present.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pic = plt.imread(path)

if pic.shape[2] == 3:
    print("No alpha channel!")
if pic.shape[2] == 4:
    print("There's an alpha channel!")
```

If you want to know whether that channel is actually used (if present), you can check if it's `1` everywhere:

```
import numpy as np
if np.allclose(pic[:, :, 3], 1):
    print("Alpha not used because 1 everywhere!")
```

Comment: Staying in Pillow with the link from @mingganz is probably better in this case. But maybe have a look at working with PNGs as `numpy` arrays anyway, it is very flexible and powerful.